# Небольшая задержка между функциями | Python

Tags: python, функции

Пытаюсь прописать функционал обычного смартфона, включая его самого, используя Tkinter. Первым делом решил прописать включение/выключение телефона через двойное нажатие ЛКМ по кнопке питания (сверху). В теории всё должно работать так:

Двойное нажатие по кнопке питания > > Появление экрана загрузки с логотипом >> ЗАДЕРЖКА 2-5 СЕКУНД >> Открытие рабочего стола.

Пытался сделать через time.sleep(s) и root.after, но при включении смартфона вся программа зависает, и в итоге появляется только картинка рабочего стола, игнорируя отображение промежуточного экрана.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from random import randrange
from time import sleep

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title('Смартфон')
root['bg'] = 'white'
c = Canvas(width=500, height=500, bg='white')
c.place(x=0,y=0)

def round_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius=25, **kwargs):
  points = [x1+radius, y1, x1+radius, y1,
            x2-radius, y1, x2-radius, y1,
            x2, y1,
            x2, y1+radius, x2, y1+radius,
            x2, y2-radius, x2, y2-radius,
            x2, y2,
            x2-radius, y2, x2-radius, y2,
            x1+radius, y2, x1+radius, y2,
            x1, y2,
            x1, y2-radius, x1, y2-radius,
            x1, y1+radius,x1, y1+radius,
            x1, y1]
  return c.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)

class Smartphone:
  def __init__(self):
    case = round_rectangle(50, 50, 250, 450, fill='gray', radius=25)
    in_case = round_rectangle(52, 52, 248, 448, fill='white', radius=25)
    #self.screen = c.create_rectangle(54,79,245,410, fill='black')
    self.screen = Canvas(c, width=191, height=331, bg='black')

    round_rectangle(110,60,190,63, radius=5, fill='gray')

    home_button_case = c.create_oval(132,413,168,445, fill='lightgray')
    self.home_button = c.create_oval(135,416,165,442, fill='white')

    self.power_button = round_rectangle(200,47,225,52, radius=5, fill='gray')

    self.smartphone_state = False

    c.tag_bind(self.power_button, '<Double-Button-1>', self.download)
    self.screen.place(x=52,y=77)

  def download(self, event):
    if not self.smartphone_state:
        self.screen['bg'] = 'gray'
        pillogo = Image.open(r'apple.ico')
        apple = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pillogo)
        image_sprite = self.screen.create_image(100,165, image=apple)
        self.screen.image = apple
        self.screen.after(5000,self.show_desktop())

  def show_desktop(self):
    self.screen['bg'] = 'white'
    pillogo = Image.open(r'theme1.png')
    theme = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pillogo)
    image_sprite = self.screen.create_image(98,165, image=theme)
    self.screen.image = theme

IPhone = Smartphone()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.screen.after(5000,self.show_desktop())
```

нужно убрать скобки, ведь вы передаете функцию, а не её результат

```
self.screen.after(5000,self.show_desktop)
```

`time.sleep` блокирует весь поток программы, в том числе и реакцию интерфейса.

Экран загрузки не показывается потому что отрисовка запланированна после завершения функции download,  а тут уже нарисовался рабочий стол.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: Возник ещё один вопрос. У меня есть класс Smartphone. В нём прописан self.screen = Canvas(). Я создал дочерний класс Desktop(Smartphone). Как мне корректно передать self.screen в дочерний класс? Все мои попытки тщетны.

Comment: Я пытался в __init__ класса Desktop прописать что-то вроде self.scr = Smartphone.screen. Не вышло. Пробовал обратиться, как self._Smartphone.screen, тоже какая-то лажа.

Comment: Super().__init__() добавь